# Implementing node-google-calendar package

Tags: node.js, api, express, google-calendar-api

i'm trying to implement node-google-calendar Node.js package. 
I've create service account and have got .json key.
Here's my code setting.js:

```
const key = require('./credentials.json').private_key;
const SERVICE_ACCT_ID = '11680319875XXXXXXXXXX';

const CALENDAR_URL = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar?cid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const CALENDAR_ID = {
  'primary': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com',
};
const TIMEZONE = 'UTC+07:00';

module.exports.calendarUrl = CALENDAR_URL;
module.exports.serviceAcctId = SERVICE_ACCT_ID;
module.exports.calendarId = CALENDAR_ID;
module.exports.key = key;
module.exports.timezone = TIMEZONE
```

Code quickstart.js:

```
const CONFIG = require('./setting.js');
const CalendarAPI = require('node-google-calendar');
let cal = new CalendarAPI(CONFIG);  
const calendarId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';

let params = {
    'start': { 'dateTime': '2017-05-20T07:00:00+08:00' },
    'end': { 'dateTime': '2017-05-20T08:00:00+08:00' },
    'location': 'Coffeeshop',
    'summary': 'Breakfast',
    'status': 'confirmed',
    'description': '',
    'colorId': 1
};

cal.Events.insert(calendarId, params)
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('inserted event:');
    console.log(resp);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: insertEvent-' + err.message);
  });
```

It returns error:

> Error:
>   insertEvent-{"origin":"Events.insert","error":{"statusCode":"403(Forbidden)","errorBody":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reas
>   on":"forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}],"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}}}

Anyone can discover where the error is? or What step do i miss? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Inside the the JSON file where all your credentials are, there should be an email address for the service account.

You need to share the calendar you're trying to update with the email address associated with the service account. Since you're inserting into the calendar, you will also need to give that service account email address write permissions to the calendar.

Comment: If this answer was correct, please mark it as such to help future developers that come across the same issue.

Comment: Is it possible to edit an event with nodejs? @francisco In the docs, the api only supports java python ruby and php

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular module you're using, but it's entirely possibly using the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and using the [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) API. But you'll need to raise a different question for that if you need more help.